# Cache busting is not working sometimes after production build in angular 7

Tags: angular, caching, angular-cli, browser-cache, angular-cache

Our app uses the node.js Core & Angular version 7.2

We are frequently rollout production build of the Angular app to deploy the changes 3-4 times in a month.

I have received some client's complaints who are unable to see changes unless they clear their cache or hard reload the page in the browser.

I thought `ng build --prod` created unique hashes so it would handle cache-busting, But it doesn't seem to be happening.

In `angular.json` I have below configuration for the production build

```
"production": {
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
   ]
}
```

After running `ng build --prod` it is generating hashed files and it's different from previous version based on changes. Also, I have configured the server to do not cache `index.html`. then why sometimes users need to hard reload the page or clear the cache manually to get the latest changes?

Is there any way I can combat this issue besides telling clients to clear their cache?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure your not cache header for index.html is working for them?

Comment: @AakashGarg Yes, I am getting this header in network tab for index.html  `Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0`

Comment: if new index.html is getting served it should serve bundles with new hash. please also include meta tags for no cache in your index.html

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to add meta tags for no cache in `index.html` because from the server-side already passing headers to do not cache file. If we add meta to file still it will be ignored by headers and meta tags for cache control is easily be ignored when there is a proxy between client and server

Comment: Any development on this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Did you guys figure this out?

Comment: The problem is with your hosting (IIS, node.js, etc...) not with angular or the cli - you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: why cant i add a bounty here?

Comment: Did you check this link: https://medium.com/acute-angular/angular-rookie-mistakes-how-to-cache-bust-an-angular-2-application-in-production-c4e4d1c48514

Answer (score 0):

angular old version:

```
ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=all
```

For the newer version of angular ( for example Angular 10) the command is now updated:

```
ng build --prod --aot --outputHashing=all
```